# What C++ idioms should C++ programmers use?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, idioms, c++-faq

What C++ idioms should C++ programmers know?

By C++ idioms, I mean design patterns or way of doing certain things that are only applicable for C++ or more applicable for C++ than most other languages.

Why one should use the idioms, and what do the idioms accomplish?

Comment: Anything that is applicable to C++ is generally applicable to other lnaguages (becuase C++ covers a lot of different programming styles).

Comment: Can you do RAII and PIMPL in that many other languages?

Comment: @Partial: RAII yes, its just more natural in C++ than in most languages.

Comment: Off the top of my head yes. Perl (an old evil language supports both if you know how to do OO in Perl). I would be surprised if nearly every OO language supported both of these (though for RAII it requires a non GC OO language (at a guess Smalltalk would support it (though I don't know for sure on that)).

Comment: You don't need non-GC languages for that, see e.g. C# and the common `using(A a = new A()) { ... }` utilizing `IDisposable`.

Comment: You can do RAII in Python with with-statements, for example. RAII just isn't automatically applied to every variable.

Comment: @gf. True. But thats only just prettier than using try {} catch {} finally {} to implement RAII. RAII should require no action on the part of the user of the object. The thing that C++ has managed to do with RAII is push the responcability of correct usage onto the designer of the class __not__ the user of the class.

Comment: @Martin: Good point, somehow i didn't think of the design-side enforcement as an attribute of RAII.

Comment: I wouldn't consider C#'s using statements an example of RAII. The problem is that you still can't let the object manage the resource, which is the point of RAII, you still have to do it manually when you *create* the object, you just get some syntactic sugar to make it look nicer.

Comment: The object still manages the resources it owns, while `using` manages the object.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is one [list](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms).  If I had to pick a couple I might go with the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern or Virtual Contstructors.

Comment: Great list I often consult; however Curiously recurring Template would be very low on my list as something every C++ programmer would need to know.

Comment: @Elemental - Agreed. I may have misread the question but I thought it mentioned uniquely C++ and CRTP seems to qualify in that respect.

Answer (score 55):

By far the single most important "pattern" to learn and know that's (nearly) unique to C++ is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).

Edit: (To answer extra question edited into the question). You use RAII primarily to (semi-)automate resource management. The most obvious use is freeing resources owned by objects when the owning objects go out of scope, such as freeing memory or closing files.

Comment: +1.  Unfortunately also the idiom with the worst name.

Comment: Don;t get me wrong its one of the more important ones in C++, but its not even close to being unique to C++. Though C++ has made it famous.

Comment: I think it's not about things that are unique to C++; rather, it's about things that are uniquely ubiquitous in C++; something you can't really get by without knowing, which you possibly could in some other languages. RAII would definitely be such a thing.

Comment: Agree, RAII is super important in C++, being smart pointers an integral part of it.

Comment: The question clearly states: "things that are only applicable for C++ "

Comment: @Martin: "only applicable for C++ or more applicable for C++ than most other languages."

Comment: RAII is the C++ way of implementing the /release pattern/.

Comment: C++ has made it famous because memory leaks do not appear in GC-language and memory is by far the most obvious resource. Unfortunately it means that people that are unaware of this idiom have trouble managing DB Connections or sockets etc... the 'using' construct is retarded in my opinion since it puts the burden on EVERY user instead of the sole class writer :/

Answer (score 11):

PIMPL, aka **P** ointer to **IMPL** ementation ?

Comment: I personally hate it. :/

Comment: Well, you don't have to use it everywhere :)

Comment: Technically, you don't _have_ to use it _anywhere_.  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, binary compatibility is important sometimes, and it's the only practical way to ensure it.

Comment: It also significantly reduces compilation time (by reducing explicit dependencies), and god knows how C++ programmers suffer from it!

Comment: On the other hand, without long compile times, many of us would not be able to spend _nearly_ as much time here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis... Agreed :D

Answer (score 8):

Template metaprogramming.  It's great because it's basically compile-time duck typing, so you get most of the flexibility of duck typing with the speed of static typing.

Comment: Ducks *can't* be taped.

Comment: +1 For *duck typing*. I always think that duck typing is the runtime version of SFINAE

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get the most out of the STL then iterators and functors/function objects are essential idioms.  The use of iterators also implicitly relies on the 'half-open range' idiom too.

Comment: Very true! Have you heard about sequence constructors and conversion constructors?

Comment: Do you mean like `iota()`?  Another omission from the list is generator objects.

Comment: To be honest, I am not familiar with iota(), but I've posted an answer with an example.

Answer (score 6):

Exploiting Strong Typing and `const` correctness is also extremely helpful.

I also prohibit default copy constructors and assignment operators. I actually go beyond that, but those are the most common. I think life would be easier if they were not implicit.

Answer (score 5):

RAII, COW, pimpl, law of demeter (not sure if can be classified as idiom), type traits and policies. (COW and law of demeter are not limited to C++ though)

Comment: Traits is somthing I have not seen anywhere else (but then again I have not been looking that hard).