# Famous design patterns that a C++ programmer should know

Tags: c++, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What C++ idioms should C++ programmers use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759613/what-c-idioms-should-c-programmers-use)

After reading books like C++ Primer, Effective C++ and TC++PL I want to learn some important design patterns.

So, what are the famous design patterns that every C++ programmer should know?

Comment: Why someone voted on "Not a real question" ? x-(

Comment: Lots of programming enthusiasts already asked same question.

Comment: My question is C++ specific,not just related to design patterns....I think they didn't read  `... that a C++ programmer should know`

Comment: I'd like to add that as well as learning design patterns you should also learn when to use them and when to **not** use them. I'm interested in any answers people come up with, but try to give bounds for the usefulness of the pattern when possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The obvious answer is the Gang-Of-Four patterns from the famous book. These are the same patterns that get listed all over the place.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Beyond that, have a look around Martin Fowlers web site...

http://martinfowler.com/

There's a fair bit on there - the "famous" one is probably "dependency injection". Most others are pretty domain specific, though.

"Mixin layers" can be interesting for C++. A template class takes its own base as a template parameter, so that the template can be used to add the same functionality to many different classes, or as a composition method so that various features can be easily included/excluded for a library. The curiously recurring template trick is sometimes used as well (the original base is the final fully-composed class) so that the various mixin layers can do some degree of "reflection", so that intermediate methods can be defined in terms of fully-composed member types etc. Of course it can be a bit prone to unresolvable cyclic dependencies, if you're not careful.

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=505148

---

Note - "the original base" doesn't mean the original base class that's inhereted from as that would cause an illegal inheritance cycle - it's just a template parameter used to refer to, to access the types/constants/etc in the final result and perhaps for metaprogramming reflection techniques.

I honestly don't know at this point if I was confused when I wrote "base", or just chose a confusing word.

Answer (score 26):

C++-specific ones: RAII and PIMPL.

Comment: Hard to say which of these is most important. PIMPL doesn't get used enough, perhaps because of fears of indirect call overhead and effectively forcing the object onto the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: The best answer here, as the question was rather about C++-specific patterns. I could only add `SFINAE` to the list. I know it is rather a rule, not a pattern, but this rules usage itself can be qualified as a pattern.

Answer (score 9):

Read the [**Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Yes, it does.

Comment: I just didn't want the name of a `Design Pattern ` book.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: It's not *a* design pattern book. It's *the* design pattern book. It's also called Gang of Four, for its authors.

Comment: @Greyfade: Ok fine. I have accepted Steve's answer because I think only his answer is `complete` :)

Comment: Is this book written with C++ in mind?

Answer (score 9):

In no particular order, the Gang of Four patterns I see and use most, are probably the following:

- Composite
- Template Method
- Abstract Factory
- Singleton (much hated, but everywhere)
- Visitor
- Builder
- Proxy

Answer (score 8):

I suggest reading [**Head First Design Patterns**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126). It's a fun read, and you'll learn about a lot of the common design patterns.

Comment: I guess that book of for Java design patterns?

Comment: @kami: Yes, the code examples are in Java, but the patterns apply to all OO languages.

Answer (score 8):

The think pattern. It's a silver bullet.

Comment: I thought "silver bullets" were the magic solutions where you don't have to think. Not many of those in development.